# Flow to Mass Update Records Works, but need it to refresh page so values show without manually refreshing

Tags: automation

I have a screen flow that mass updates for the status of selected records on a related list. The flow works, but the refresh does not. Any suggestions on why it is not working? RIght now I have the updatedPage by unofficalSF installed. The SDP training logs that I am updating are a related list on the Skills Dev Pathway object, and in the flow, the Skills Dev pathway object is not referenced.

The SDP Training Logs are what status is being updated on a related list on the Skills Dev Pathway object. Once those are updated via the screen flow, I want it to come back to the SKills Dev page, with the statuses updated without manually refreshing.

[image: ScreenFlow]

[image]

Comment: What is updatedPage? I see [Update Screen](https://unofficialsf.com/update-screen/) on unofficialsf, but it'd be good to confirm what the action is doing (a link to the code if from unofficialsf) as that's most likely the focus to debug.

Comment: I meant Update Screen. It looks like it won't work through a button, so I'm wondering if there is another way to do what I need it to.